# getting "IndexError: list index" out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('/Users/Ciel/Downloads/python/us-500.csv', 'r') as ldap_list:
data = csv.reader(ldap_list)
#next(data)
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(10))
for row in sortedlist:
    if row:
        applications[i].append(row[3])
        recipients[i].append(row[1])
        users[i].append(row[8])
        if not recipients[i] == recipients[i-1]:
            send_email(recipients[i],users[i],applications[i])
        else:
            applications[i] = [applications[i]]
            applications[i].append(str(applications[i-1]))
            users[i] = [users[i]]
            users[i] = append(str(users[i-1]))
            send_email(recipients[i],users[i],applications[i])
        #app_count += 1
    #application_list = application_list.append(str(applications[i]))
    i += 1
```

Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Ciel/Downloads/python/ldap_notifi.py", line 24, in 
applications[i].append(row[3])
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index out or range: means that you are indexing a value in a list that doesn't exist, like

```
a = [1,2,3,4] 
print(a[4])
```

**What I think is the problem**

`application[i]` doesn't exist for some value of i.

**what you could do**

put the code inside a try/except block and print `application[i]` in the except block and also print `i`, also row might not have 4 values, so `row[3]` might also be the issue, without data and some more code, this is the best I can help.

Comment: it's error in the input, when I append something to the string

Comment: @ciel can you please upvote this accepted answer? I need some reputation :)